# localhost WordPress include file.php

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

In my wordpress footer I'm getting file php from other site.

```
<?php include('http://www.othersite.com/1.php'); ?>
```

How to working this in localhost ?

Got errors:

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in D:\Design\AppServ\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mythems\footer.php on line 21

Warning: include(http://www.othersite.com/1.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in D:\Design\AppServ\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mythems\footer.php on line 21

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'http://www.othersite.com/1.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in D:\Design\AppServ\www\wordpress\wp-content\mythems\halongcruise\footer.php on line 21
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get content and show it on your footer, here we go:

```
<?php 

    $response = wp_remote_get('http://www.othersite.com/1.php');
    echo wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

***SOLUTION 1:***
Add or uncomment the following line on your `php.ini`:

```
allow_url_fopen = ON
```

restart `apache`.

***SOLUTION 2:***

Add the following to the .htaccess file:

```
php_flag allow_url_fopen on
```

http://www.solo-technology.com/blog/2010/04/07/quick-fix-for-url-file-access-is-disabled-issues/

Comment: My php.ini is: allow_url_fopen = ON and i'm add php_flag allow_url_fopen on to .htaccess but not running

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include file from different server, then you need to allow inclusion of remote files, the directive **allow_url_include** must be set to On in **php.ini**. By default this setting is disabled/not allowed in most web servers (php.ini) so you can not use the include to include the files from a remote addresss for security reasons.

On a security-oriented point of view this practice is bad. So whatever you want to do just keep in mind what I'd try to say.

If you don't want to include another sites file then it is simple to include a file from your server like,

```
<?php include('1.php'); ?> //Use relative or absolute path inside include
```

Reference: http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/tests/allow_url_include.html

Answer (score 0):

For include file use

```
wp_remote_get( 'http://www.example.com/index.html' );
```

for retrieve included data data on your site

```
wp_remote_retrieve_body()
```

You can use for finally this issue bellows code.

```
<?php 
$get_include = wp_remote_get( 'http://www.example.com/myfile.php' );
echo wp_remote_retrieve_body($get_include);
 ?>
```